# Dealing with two jQuery versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

On my page I use scrollify and bootstrap responsive menu.
Scrollify works with jQuery 1.6 and Bootstrap with 2.1.4.

According to some posts here I've tried a few solutions but they do not work or maybe I did something wrong.

What I've tried was:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/jquery-1.6.js"></script>
<script>var $j = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 console.log($().jquery); // This prints v2.1.4
 console.log($j().jquery); // This prints v1.6
});
```

In both codes the 1.6 version should have $j instead of $ and it didn't work:

```
<script>
    $j(function() {
       $j.scrollify({
          section : "section",
       });
    });
</script>
```

Live example:
http://solutionsmvo.nazwa.pl/tyszka/
(now responsive menu works and scrollify doesn't work)

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead? It will work with any version > 1.6

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing either or at the bottom of your page just above the `</body>` tag? That sometimes can help